# What is the difference between את (et, with) and עם (`im, with) in Biblical Hebrew?

Tags: hebrew

I understand that there is the definite direct object marker את in Hebrew, but I wonder what, if any, is the difference in usage between the "with" את compared with the other preposition meaning "with", עם. In Modern Hebrew, the second is more common, while in the Bible, both seem pretty common.

Comment: Where are you getting the idea that the word את means "with"? I don't think that is the meaning of the word.  For example, in the 10 Commandments, "honor thy father and thy mother" is כַּבֵּ֥ד אֶת־אָבִ֖יךָ וְאֶת־אִמֶּ֑ךָ.

Comment: Please consider supporting the [Semitic Languages Area 51 proposal.](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/113173/semitic-languages) and following and upvoting questions there to help this become a Stack Exchange site. Once (if) it is accepted to beta,  questions of this type would welcome and on-topic there but beta can only be reached with additional support.

Comment: @conceptualinertia את is the direct object marker *and* the preposition "with". The first is vocalised with segol (אֶת), the second with tsere (אֵת).

Comment: @Keelan Exodus 2:24 contains את first as object marker, then three times as "with"' **all** vocalized with segol. Vocalization of את as object marker with tsere occurs in Deuteronomy 6:5. The vocalization is dependent on position in phrase and intonation (ta'am) of preceding word.

Comment: @conceptualinertia וַיְהִי כִּי אָרְכוּ לוֹ שָׁם הַיָּמִים וַיַּשְׁקֵף אֲבִימֶלֶךְ מֶלֶךְ פְּלִשְׁתִּים בְּעַד הַחַלּוֹן וַיַּרְא וְהִנֵּה יִצְחָק מְצַחֵק אֵת רִבְקָה אִשְׁתּוֹ

Comment: @AbuMunirIbnIbrahim right, what I said was a rule of thumb.

Comment: @AbuMunirIbnIbrahim I don't think that is a good example. That sentence reads fine without the "with" (or the את). It means that Isaac was pleasing Rebecca his wife (i.e. foreplay).  Even Exodus 2:24 does not clearly mean "with." It might simply mean like in Leviticus 26:43: וְזָכַרְתִּ֖י אֶת־בְּרִיתִ֣י יַעֲק֑וֹב וְאַף֩ אֶת־בְּרִיתִ֨י יִצְחָ֜ק וְאַ֨ף אֶת־בְּרִיתִ֧י אַבְרָהָ֛ם אֶזְכֹּ֖ר

Comment: @conceptualinertia צחק isn't transitive in OT Hebrew so that reading doesn't work. See Genesis 21:6,9 and Psalms 104:26, לִוְיָתָן זֶה יָצַרְתָּ לְשַׂחֶק בּוֹ. See the second entry for את in the Even Shoshan dictionary or the many examples in the Even Shoshan concordance.

Comment: @AbuMunirIbnIbrahim I stand corrected on את meaning "with."  But I don't think your evidence that צחק can't be transitive is that strong. I am no grammarian, but if I am trying to please/entertain someone else, then maybe it can be transitive.  Psalms 104:26 and Genesis 21:9 are where the subject of the sentence is trying to please themselves using someone or something else.  Genesis 21:6 while less clear, is also understood by Rashi, the Radak, and others as people hearing laughing because of Sarah giving birth. Sarah is the cause of their own enjoyment. They aren't trying to make her laugh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert in Hebrew, but here goes.

I think the question misses a couple of things when dealing with אֶת.  This term can have two different functions depending on the context.  The vowel pointings or the context determines the difference.  In one case it functions as a direct object marker as your question suggests and in the other it functions as a preposition.

Your question contrasts the usage of אֶת when it is being used as a proposition.  Here is what Waltke says in his Syntax of the use as a preposition:

> The basic sense is comitative (‘with’); it may mark accompaniment (companionship, fellowship; # 1), interest (accompaniment, literal or metaphorical, for the purpose of helping; ## 2–4), or the complement of verbs of dealing, speaking, and making (## 5–7). The object of ʾt may also be an addition (‘beside, alongside of, in addition to’; # 8). The preposition has a spatial sense closely related to this last (‘near’; # 9); compare English ‘alongside of,’ as in ‘There is a temple alongside of the palace’ and ‘There is a priesthood alongside of the monarchy.’ The possessive can be marked with ʾt (‘have’; # 10).

The second term עִם is also a preposition.

Here too is what Waltke says in his syntax on this preposition:

> It expresses a variety of comitative relations (‘with’).  The most common sense involves accompaniment (fellowship and companionship, person + person; ‘with’; ## 1–3) or addition (‘with, along with, and’; # 4); ʿm often marks a personal complement after verbs (‘with, to,’ ## 5–7; adversative, ‘against,’ # 8). The locus of psychological interest can be marked with ʿm (‘with, in’; ## 9–10).

Also the following:

> With verbs of motion and the like ʿm marks the end point of an action (‘beside, at’; # 11). The preposition is also used in comparative constructions.

Here is where I speculate a little.  The first would be more spatial and therefore it corresponds more to the idea of alongside or near.  Then the second would be more in line with the idea of "with" as we would use it in English.

Comment: This is correct. Although the common senses are very similar, עם has the possibility to clearly differentiate two entities as opposing each other while את cannot do that. עם is a very broad preposition that can be highly similar to את on the one hand (symmetric) and ב on the other (asymmetric, like Waltke's "adversative"). It depends a lot on context.

Comment: There is also a tendency towards עם instead of את in later Hebrew (Joüon-Muraoka, 2006, *A Grammar of Biblical Hebrew*, p. 316).